# Glide does not load image from cache location

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-storage, android-glide

I use the following code to download images from `firebase storage` to a local file:

```
val sharedReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("url to my bucket")
    val localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg")
    sharedReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener {
   
    Glide.with(context).load(localFile.toUri().path).into(myImageView)

    }
```

But the url I get back from that is like this:

```
/data/user/0/com.example.myapp/cache/images1018011169077473514jpg
```

And glide does not load the image in. How can I load the image using glide in the imageView.

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create a temp file, directly show the image via Glide.
It will cache it anyways.

Comment: thanks for the response. I see now that it does automatically cache the image, so I can still use it when the device is offline. Thanks so much.